# Opencv2.3 and Qt Creator 2.4.1 linker error

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am running opencv and qt.I have successfully added the includes for the opencv.But when I am doing cvLoadImage,there is a linker error.

This is my code:

```
void MainWindow:on_pushButton_clicked()
{

img = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\MLS-PROGRAMER\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Image_processing\\Image_processing \\thres.png");
// cvNamedWindow("Image",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
// cvShowImage("Image", img);
// cvWaitKey(40);

}
```

This is the error message:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvLoadImage referenced in function "private: void __thiscall MainWindow:n_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AAEXXZ)

debug\FIDAS.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

My project file is like this

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2012-05-29T10:31:40
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT += core gui

TARGET = FIDAS
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += mainwindow.h

FORMS += mainwindow.ui


INCLUDEPATH += C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\include\opencv \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib \

CONFIG(release,debug|release)
{
LIBS += C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_calib3d231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_contrib231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_core231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_features2d231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_flann231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_gpu231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_haartraining_engine.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_highgui231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_imgproc231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_legacy231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_ml231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_objdetect231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_ts231.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_video231.lib \
}

CONFIG(debug,debug|release)
{
LIBS += C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_calib3d231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_contrib231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_core231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_features2d231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_flann231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_gpu231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_haartraining_engined.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_highgui231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_imgproc231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_legacy231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_ml231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_objdetect231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_ts231d.lib \
C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\opencv_video231d.lib \
}
```

Any help for this issues would be great.?

Comment: add opencv_highguid231.lib also and then try...

Comment: are those spaces really there?

Comment: @spyke I did that but no change in the output

Comment: @lakshmikant The order of the libs is relevant (at least on Linux), try putting highgui first and core last or vice versa. On Linux the linker tries to resolve symbols from last to first.

Comment: @bjoernz i tried that too..got no success.

Comment: If this is a case of problematic linking order, I usually use a trick of just adding the list of all the linking libs twice. That should take care of any circular dependencies. Otherwise you can probably just build OpenCV statically (there's a configuration switch for it in it's CMake configuration), to get around any problems with libraries that can't be found at runtime...

Comment: Did u have opencvMinGW libraries? without MinGW libs and dlls you can't integrate Qt with opencv 2.3

Answer (score 2):

I use config like this for my own project:

```
LIBS += D:/OpenCV-2.3.0/build/lib/libopencv_core230.dll.a
```

I use C++ API instead of using C API, i.e. `imread` instead of `cvLoadImage`.

Comment: I did that but the program will not run when built. It will exit "The Application did not run successfully". I suspect something to do with 64-bit libraries. it's all too confusing.

Comment: run it outside of qtcreator, and see what dlls it needs, and then add dll directory path to the PATH

Comment: may be it's a gpu related problem

Answer (score 2):

You should actually specify the link path (where to find the libraries) and then the list of libraries to be linked:

```
LIBS += -L C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib -lopencv_contrib231 -lopencv_core231 -lopencv_features2d231 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

[Step 8](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html) describes it for all architectures.

Basically, you have to specify your library path with -L and then add the library file with

`-l<libname_without_extension>`

For unix (installed in default place):

```
unix: LIBS += -lopencv_core
unix: LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
```

For windows (your problem):

```
win32: LIBS += -L C:\OpenCV2.3\opencv\build\gpu\x64\lib\ -lopencv_core231
```